# How to make an icon become transparent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project and the designer made 2 sets of icons ,first set is white on a
 `opacity (0.5);` background and another set should be transparent so the background image can be seen through the icon .

Is there a way to make them with css become transparent so they cut their container background and the body background image can be seen through them ?  I want to make the same for the text and for the checkbox which will be custom and have an icon when checked.
  Hope there is a solution for this as i have searched high and low for a solution.

I have a little code example :

```
 <body style="background-image:url('image.png');>
   <ul>
    <li>
      <i>Icon</i>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

It is not the same question , i m trying to make image fully transparent and to make it crop the li white background so the body background is shown through it .Thus the image will have the same border lines but with the body background as it s contents . When you scroll the contents of the ul all the images will have diffrent background as the body background is full of color . Hope i made myself clear , if not i will try to better clarify the situation . But i think the client and he's designer is dumb and dont know this is hard next to paradox thing to achieve .

Comment: you would need to use the icon without the background and then set the background opacity using css: `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` then you can just remove this when you need to see through it - or if you need the actual icon to become transparent then you should use the [`opacity` css](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/)

Comment: watch out, transparency affects also the children...

Comment: Dosent work like that , i want to see the body background , not the li background that is white .

Answer (score 0):

this could help you:

```
.container
{
background-size:80px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;top:8px;left:8px;width:100%;height:100%;

background-color:transparent;
backface-visibility:visible;    
background-image: url('../img-folder/image.png');
}
```

the three last option is important...

Comment: Dosen't work , i dont this what i m trying to achive is possible yet , i found somewere how to do it with canvas crop or something but thats not a reliable solution .I'll still try to find a solutin or something . Tnx for the answer .